# Activity recreates even though no one calls it

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an activity A which shows different screens. I chose to show multiple views in the same activity, by using `setContentView`.

When you launch the app, Activity A shows the default screen. You then choose an option and the activity shows you another set of options by setting setContentView to another view. This new view now takes you to a new activity(Activity B) when you click it, and Activity A calls `finish()`

If I now end Activity B, by calling `finish()` on it, I am being taken back to Activity A, and it calls it's `onCreate()`. I can't figure out what's wrong here. Why would an activity recreate itself when Activity B never called an intent for Activity A?

```
view.findViewById(R.id.quit).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        finish();
    }
});
```

Comment: How does Activity A take you to Activity B? Is it by calling `startActivityForResult()?` or `startActivity()`?

Comment: @DanielGabriel `startActivity()`

Comment: You sure you're not starting Activity A from B? :P I can't image how Activity A could be created if what you're telling us is correct.

Comment: @Carnal Updated the question with the code

Comment: What else do you expect it should do when the current activity finishes itself?  You haven't told it to go somewhere definitive (such as HOME), so it's just going to pop up a level in the activity stack.  Just one more way in which 'Quit' buttons are a difficult fit with the Android usage model, and rarely appropriate except in very obscure / during-development cases.

Comment: @ChrisStratton its a game, so when the user taps on quit, I want the app's activities to end. Also, if I am not wrong, finishing an activity does not leave it in the history stack anymore. So the app should go back to home.

Comment: I would have expected some context.startActivity(intent); finish(); … looking at my code I now remember having seen this in your code. What I do in some cases where I don't want an activity on the stack is to construct something like A calling B for result and when the result comes back to A, it calls C. This way, B should be out of the way when C finishes. But anyway, startActivity(B); finish(); should work, too.

Comment: @Giszmo this activity just needs to finish itself, Activity A already did `startActivity(intentForActivityB);finish();` Its really odd, since all other apps I have developed work just fine with finishing. This pretty much how I prevent user's from ending on the login activity once they have logged in.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely because the purpose of `onCreate()` is to create the Activity's state as it was when it left.  You can't under any circumstances assume that an `Activity` will maintain its state once the user leaves it.  Views are memory intensive, and the system is going to dump it as soon as it needs more memory for the current top Activity. If this happens then the system must recreate the `Activity` to its original state before the system dumped it.

You can save states via the `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` method.  The bundle that's passed in to `onCreate` is the same bundle you set in `onSaveInstanceState()`, so all parameters will be there.  Then you can rebuild just as it was.